# context swtich between thread.start and thread.join

Tags: c#, .net

Is there any bad effect if there is context switch between thread.start and thread.join?
if a thread finish executing before join, what will happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really does depend a bit on what the child thread is doing for you, but generally if the main thread creates a child and then does more concurrent work while that child thread is away and the child finishes its execution first you will, at worst, have a race condition. This is when you have certain things that happen in you code that depend on the child thread doing work but not implementing controls to stop the main thread proceeding if it actually depends on that work being finished.

Ultimately a call to .join will result in an instantanious return as all the method does is wait until the child thread/s have finished execution. However, do watch out for accidental race conditions, they can be a right nightmare to debug!

Answer (score 0):

Join will return immediately if the thread has already finished executing.